# Read csv to dict of dicts

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Lets say I have this csv file:

```
Header1, Header2, Header3
key1,    1,       2
key2,    3,       4
```

I'd like to convert it to the following dict:

```
{Header2: {key1: 1, key2: 3}, Header3: {key1: 2, key2: 4}}
```

Is there a simple way to do this?
I tried using csv DictReader or pandas, but did not get a simple way, although this looks to me like a common use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `to_dict` method of pandas' DataFrame instance. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delimiter=r',\s+', index_col=0)
print(df.to_dict())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `csv` module:

```
import csv 

f = open(csv_file_path)
reader = csv.DictReader(f)

fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
result = {fieldname:{} for fieldname in fieldnames[1:]}
for row in reader:
    for fieldname in fieldnames[1:]:
        result[fieldname][row['Header1'].strip()] = row[fieldname].strip()
```